# Não consigo aceder à minha base de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com o seguinte problema, estou a tentar alterar o ano das datas que tenho na minha base de dados, e para isso estou a usar:

```
mysqli_fetch_row
```

Mas não estou a conseguir, retorna sempre falha. Também fiz uma conexão à base de dados e aparentemente está a funcionar porque não retorna com erro. agradecia imenso qualquer tipo de ajuda prestada. Se a pergunta não estiver devidamente clara, solicitem, que farei as devidas alterações. Obrigado

Código:

```
 <?php 
 //Create a database connection
     $dbhost = "localhost";
     $dbuser = "root";
     $dbpass = "";
     $dbname = "bd-aircaw-1";
     $connection =mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM voo ";
    $query .= "WHERE DataPartida = 2014-11-01 18:00:00";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result) {
        die ("Database query failed.");
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        var_dump($row);
        echo "<hr />";
    }
```

Comment: Valores de data devem estar entre aspas simples.

Comment: Já modifiquei as aspas para simples mas não surtiu efeito continua a dar o erro "Database query failed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua conexão esta incompleta, veja o exemplo do [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp): `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`

Você deve usar aspas para buscar por `datas` e `strings` no `BD`:

```
`$query .= "WHERE DataPartida = \"2014-11-01 18:00:00\"";`
```

Comment: Já alterei o código, obrigado pela sugestão, realmente não reparei nos parâmetros em falta, mas apesar de ter retificado, alterei e continua sem correr; o programa.

Comment: Qual o erro que dá agora?

Comment: Acho que tem outro problema em sua SQL, editarei minha resposta.

Comment: Dá o mesmo erro: "Database query failed." Penso que seja alguma coisa relacionada com os querys, não devem estar a encontram valores nenhuns, mas já verifiquei os valores e parece-me não haver erros.

Comment: Obrigado era mesmo esse o problema :) Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código com problema:

```
$query .= "WHERE DataPartida = 2014-11-01 18:00:00";
```

Acrescente aspas simples ou aspas dupla com escape:

```
$query .= "WHERE DataPartida = '2014-11-01 18:00:00'";
ou
$query .= "WHERE DataPartida = \"2014-11-01 18:00:00\"";
```